# C++ print Char using pointer address

Tags: c++, c, pointers

If I have an address to string which is

```
(DWORD*)PEFile->ExportTable.pNames[i];
```

how can i print that string , notice that i do not know the size of that string

Comment: That's actually a pointer to a `DWORD`. What's the type of `PEFile->ExportTable.pNames`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little hard to interpret because its ambiguous, but...

If .pNames is itself a null-terminated character array (c-string) or a C++ string, just do:

```
std::cout << (DWORD*)PEFile->ExportTable.pNames;
```

If .pNames[i] is a null-terminated character array (c-string), just do:

```
std::cout << (DWORD*)PEFile->ExportTable.pNames[i];
```

If its a non-null terimnated character array and you don't know the size, you're in trouble.

If you have the size of the character array and it's not null terminated though, you can just iterate over it and print.  `std::copy(PEFile->ExportTable.pNames[i], PEFile->ExportTable.pNames[i] + length, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));` would do that for you in one line.

Comment: Note that the cast to `DWORD*` is likely to have you print the string's address, not its contents.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is [null-terminated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), you can simply use:

```
std::cout << PEFile->ExportTable.pNames[i] << std::endl;
```

(use `std::wcout` if `UNICODE` is defined and `pNames[i]` is a `LPCWSTR`.)

If have neither a null terminator not the string length, then you're screwed!

Answer (score 0):

In case you're serious about this being C rather than C++:

```
printf("%s", PEFile->ExportTable.pNames[i]);
```